# WPF - Get Hyperlink command from data?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, hyperlink

In WPF, how can I get a reference to the Command that a Hyperlink should invoke from an object property?

I am creating a WPF application, using the MVVM pattern. A list box in the main window dislays hyperlinks. Each hyperlink will invoke one of the view model's ICommand properties when it is clicked. How do I specify which ICommand should be invoked?

Here is what I have tried so far: The hyperlinks are contained in ViewModel.Hyperlinks property, which is bound as the ItemsSource for the list box. The Hyperlinks property contains objects of type MyHyperlink:

```
public class MyHyperlink
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string ViewModelCommand { get; set; }
    public int RecordID { get; set; }
}
```

The MyHyperlink.ViewModelCommand property contains the name of the view model ICommand that should be invoked when the hyperlink is clicked. I want to use that value to specify a PropertyPath for the Command property of the WPF Hyperlink control
.
I tried creating a PropertyPath resource for the list box with the name of the command, but WPF won't accept that. Here is my XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Hyperlinks}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <PropertyPath x:Key="CommandPath" Path="{Binding ViewModelCommand}" />
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <Hyperlink Command="{StaticResource CommandPath}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding Path=RecordID}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
                </Hyperlink>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

How do I specify which ICommand should be invoked when the hyperlink is clicked? Do I create a resource (as shown above), or it it done some other way? I need to do this in XAML--I don't want to resort to code-behind. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your code above doesn't work because `Hyperlink.Command` is of type `ICommand`, not `string`. You either need to modify your `MyHyperlink` class so that `ViewModelCommand` is also an `ICommand`, or write an `IValueConverter` that will find the correct `ICommand` implementation given the command name in your view model.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a solution that uses an IValueConverter. It is written up as [an article on The Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/MvvmDynamicCommands.aspx). Hopefully it will help other people down the road.

Comment: In your Code Project article on Dynamic Commands, you mentioned that there was a better way than using an IValueConverter. Can you let us in on the secret?

Comment: Didn't pan out. I'm using IValueConverter. So, no secret.